# PowerShell - Comparing two Arrays return Index if failure

Tags: powershell

Good Morning!

I want to compare my new AD-User ($ADUserArray) with the Json information ($UserObjectArray) , i tried everything i could find on the Internet, but it does not seem to work.

The foreach loop was my last try, i need to iterate over the list and point out the index of the failure, if a failure happend.

```
$ADUserArray = @(
            <#0#>           $adUser.givenname;
            <#1#>           $adUser.surname;
            <#2#>           $adUser.DisplayName;
            <#3#>           $adUser.userprinzipalname;
            <#4#>           $adUser.State;
            <#5#>           $adUser.Office;
            <#6#>           $adUser.OfficePhone;
            <#7#>           $adUser.City;
            <#8#>           $adUser.Company;
            <#9#>           $adUser.EmailAddress;
            <#10#>          $adUser.Department;
            <#11#>          $adUser.Homepage;
            <#12#>          $adUser.StreetAddress;
            <#13#>          $adUser.PostalCode;
            <#14#>          $adUser.SamAccountName;
            <#15#>          $adUser.homedirectory;
            <#16#>          $adUser.titel;
            <#17#>          $adUser.HomeDrive;
            <#18#>          $adUser.ProfilePath;
            <#19#>          $adUser.Manager)

$userObjectArray = @(
            <#0#>           $userObject.givenname;
            <#1#>           $userObject.surname;
            <#2#>           $userObject.displayname;
            <#3#>           $userObject.userprinzipalname;
            <#4#>           $userObject.state;
            <#5#>           $userObject.office;
            <#6#>           $userObject.officephone;
            <#7#>           $userObject.city;
            <#8#>           $userObject.company;
            <#9#>           $userObject.emailaddress;
            <#10#>          $userObject.department;
            <#11#>          $userObject.homepage;
            <#12#>          $userObject.streetaddress;
            <#13#>          $userObject.postalcode;
            <#14#>          $userObject.samaccountname;
            <#15#>          $userObject.homedirectory;
            <#16#>          $userObject.titel;
            <#17#>          $userObject.homedrive;
            <#18#>          $userObject.profilepath;
            <#19#>          $userObject.managerName)
$index = 0

foreach  ($test in $ADUserArray) 
{
    if (??? -like ???)
    {
        Write-Host "No Failure"
    }

    else
    {
        Write-Host "Error at: " $index
    }

    $index++
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO,

You might want to look into `Compare-Object`.

I've adapted your input and code, so it works. However, you might want to keep your JSON and AD user object as close to the original as possible.

You seem to be doing strange things in your code as well. The `<#1#>` bits won't help you, since they are just comments. Also the `if (??? -like ???)`statement looks bizarre. Could you explain what you are trying to do there?

I have added an if clausule in your arrays, so that you can use 'Nulled' fields as well.

```
$ADUserArray = @(
            <#0#>           $(if($ADuser.givenname -eq $null){"No GivenName"}else{$userObject.givenname}),
            <#1#>           $(if($ADuser.surname -eq $null){"No surname"}else{$userObject.surname}),
            <#2#>           $(if($ADuser.displayname -eq $null){"No displayname"}else{$userObject.displayname}),
            <#3#>           $(if($ADuser.userprinzipalname -eq $null){"No userprinzipalname"}else{$userObject.userprinzipalname}),
            <#4#>           $(if($ADuser.state -eq $null){"No state"}else{$userObject.state}),
            <#5#>           $(if($ADuser.office -eq $null){"No office"}else{$userObject.office}),
            <#6#>           $(if($ADuser.officephone -eq $null){"No officephone"}else{$userObject.officephone}),
            <#7#>           $(if($ADuser.city -eq $null){"No city"}else{$userObject.city}),
            <#8#>           $(if($ADuser.company -eq $null){"No company"}else{$userObject.company}),
            <#9#>           $(if($ADuser.emailaddress -eq $null){"No emailaddress"} else {$userObject.emailaddress}),
            <#10#>          $(if($ADuser.department -eq $null){"No department"}else{$userObject.department}),
            <#11#>          $(if($ADuser.homepage -eq $null){"No homepage"}else{$userObject.homepage}),
            <#12#>          $(if($ADuser.streetaddress -eq $null){"No streetaddress"}else{$userObject.streetaddress}),
            <#13#>          $(if($ADuser.postalcode -eq $null){"No postalcode"}else{$userObject.postalcode}),
            <#14#>          $(if($ADuser.samaccountname -eq $null){"No samaccountname"}else{$userObject.samaccountname}),
            <#15#>          $(if($ADuser.homedirectory -eq $null){"No homedirectory"}else{$userObject.homedirectory}),
            <#16#>          $(if($ADuser.titel -eq $null){"No titel"}else{$userObject.titel}),
            <#17#>          $(if($ADuser.homedrive -eq $null){"No homedrive"}else{$userObject.homedrive}),
            <#18#>          $(if($ADuser.profilepath -eq $null){"No profilepath"}else{$userObject.profilepath}),
            <#19#>          $(if($ADuser.managerName -eq $null){"No managerName"}else{$userObject.managerName})
            )


$userObjectArray = @(
            <#0#>           $(if($userObject.givenname -eq $null){"No GivenName"}else{$userObject.givenname}),
            <#1#>           $(if($userObject.surname -eq $null){"No surname"}else{$userObject.surname}),
            <#2#>           $(if($userObject.displayname -eq $null){"No displayname"}else{$userObject.displayname}),
            <#3#>           $(if($userObject.userprinzipalname -eq $null){"No userprinzipalname"}else{$userObject.userprinzipalname}),
            <#4#>           $(if($userObject.state -eq $null){"No state"}else{$userObject.state}),
            <#5#>           $(if($userObject.office -eq $null){"No office"}else{$userObject.office}),
            <#6#>           $(if($userObject.officephone -eq $null){"No officephone"}else{$userObject.officephone}),
            <#7#>           $(if($userObject.city -eq $null){"No city"}else{$userObject.city}),
            <#8#>           $(if($userObject.company -eq $null){"No company"}else{$userObject.company}),
            <#9#>           $(if($userObject.emailaddress -eq $null){"No emailaddress"} else {$userObject.emailaddress}),
            <#10#>          $(if($userObject.department -eq $null){"No department"}else{$userObject.department}),
            <#11#>          $(if($userObject.homepage -eq $null){"No homepage"}else{$userObject.homepage}),
            <#12#>          $(if($userObject.streetaddress -eq $null){"No streetaddress"}else{$userObject.streetaddress}),
            <#13#>          $(if($userObject.postalcode -eq $null){"No postalcode"}else{$userObject.postalcode}),
            <#14#>          $(if($userObject.samaccountname -eq $null){"No samaccountname"}else{$userObject.samaccountname}),
            <#15#>          $(if($userObject.homedirectory -eq $null){"No homedirectory"}else{$userObject.homedirectory}),
            <#16#>          $(if($userObject.titel -eq $null){"No titel"}else{$userObject.titel}),
            <#17#>          $(if($userObject.homedrive -eq $null){"No homedrive"}else{$userObject.homedrive}),
            <#18#>          $(if($userObject.profilepath -eq $null){"No profilepath"}else{$userObject.profilepath}),
            <#19#>          $(if($userObject.managerName -eq $null){"No managerName"}else{$userObject.managerName})
            )

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject @($ADUserArray | select) -DifferenceObject @($userObjectArray | select) -IncludeEqual
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your super fast response!!

<#0#> those comments are just for me as an index, so i can find it faster;)

if (??? -like ???) i did not know what to put there ;D

It works, thank you! i will look further into it, apperently i didnt know what to make out of those indicators... Never in a thousand years i would come up with that solution:)